# How i can show multi lines in one line?

Tags: css, text

I want keep 3 text in one line by float in css
but after text 2,text 3 shows in next line.
I want show part of text 3 in first line.

```
<style>
.a1{
  float: left;
}
</style>
```

```
<div class="a1">/11 11 11 11 11 11 1  1111 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  1 1  1 1 1  1 1  11 1 11 1 1 1 11 1 1111 11 1 11 11 1 1/</div>
<div class="a1">/22 22 22 22 2 22 22 22 22 2 2 22 2 22 2 2 2 22 2 22222 222 22 22 2 222/</div>
<div class="a1">/33 33 33 33 33 333 3 33 3333 33 3 33 33 3 3 33 33 33 33 3 3 3/</div>
```

Comment: so you want 111 in one row and 2 and 3 in one row?

Comment: try removing `float`, if you need to show them in lines, and not to float... The question is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with floats or any elements that are block-level `display` type, that's not the way the line box model works. You need to use inline elements like `span` tags.

```css
span:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<span class="a1">11 11 11 11 11 11 1  1111 1 1  1 1 1 1 1  1 1  1 1 1  1 1  11 1 11 1 1 1 11 1 1111 11 1 11 11 1 1</span>
<span class="a1">22 22 22 22 2 22 22 22 22 2 2 22 2 22 2 2 2 22 2 22222 222 22 22 2 222</span>
<span class="a1">33 33 33 33 33 333 3 33 3333 33 3 33 33 3 3 33 33 33 33 3 3 3</span>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/0u3z1o9g/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Float is not ment to do these kind of things, it's ment to "float" an image next to text like this: [image]
<sub>(source: [html.net](http://html.net/tutorials/css/figure016.gif))</sub>

A better solution would be to use:

```
.a1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

if you want to force it all to be on 1 line, create a parent element that has this css on it.

```css
.parent {
    white-space: nowrap; /* this prevents it from being on multiple lines*/
    font-size: 0; /* this prevents the space between the lines */
}
.a1 {
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size:12pt; /* set the font-size back to whatever you want */
}


/* Some extra styling */
.a1:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
.a1:last-of-type {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a1">/11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1111 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 1 11 1 1 1 11 1 1111 11 1 11 11 1 1/</div>
  <div class="a1">/22 22 22 22 2 22 22 22 22 2 2 22 2 22 2 2 2 22 2 22222 222 22 22 2 222/</div>
  <div class="a1">/33 33 33 33 33 333 3 33 3333 33 3 33 33 3 3 33 33 33 33 3 3 3/</div>
</div>
```